# Is there a way to autoscale a Redis cluster on Kubernetes?

Tags: redis, kubernetes, autoscaling

After some readings, it seems there is no sustainable solution for **auto-scaling** Redis on Kubernetes without adding a controller like [Maestro](https://github.com/adenda/maestro/wiki/Kubernetes-Redis-controller-for-autoscaling-a-Redis-cluster). Unfortunatly the project seems a bit dead.

What are some alternatives for autoscaling Redis ?

Edit: Redis is a statefull app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autoscale anything on Kubernetes, it requires some type of controller. For general autoscaling, the community is rallying around the [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/). By default, you configure it to scale based on CPU utilization.

If you want to scale based on metrics other than CPU utilization and you're using the [Redis helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis), you can easily configure it to run a Prometheus metric sidecar and can set the autoscaler to scale based on one of those values.

Comment: My bad, i should've said i want to autoscale statefull apps (like Redis). Scaling up is not an issue, scaling down is a different kettle of fish.